# Check to see if all the elements of an array are the same

Tags: arrays, vba

I am not an expert in VBA, but I need to find if all the elements in an array are the same. Is there a function which we can use to check if all the elements are same?

Comment: Just iterate through all elements and use one variable to store the previous element. If actual element is different from last element they are not all equal. If you reach the end without differences they're all equal.

Comment: Look at this question + answer from earlier today on how to use the workbook function Correl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964791/unable-to-get-correl-property-of-the-worksheetfunction-class-error

Answer (score 8):

This is essentially the same as [KopBuH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11969220/698590), but I prefer this method of looping/boolean assignment...

```
Function ElementsSame(arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim l As Long
    ElementsSame = True
    For l = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(0) <> arr(l) Then
            ElementsSame = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next l
End Function
```

Comment: Wouldn't you also need to check arr(1) with arr(2) and arr(2) with arr(3)? If I understand this correctly, this just compares every element with the zeroth element.

Comment: Nevermind, I see why that works.

Comment: @wizlog Not in this case, no. By using one element to compare to every other, ANY instance where the result is false means the whole set is false. If, after the first run, there are no differences found, then that is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'm sure other confused people who stumble on this answer appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function to check any array of a variables of any type. If this function returns TRUE, it means all elements in array is equals.

```
Function IsAllElementsTheSame(arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim buf As Variant
    buf = arr(0)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Do While (buf = arr(i) And i < UBound(arr))
    i = i + 1
    Loop
    IsAllElementsTheSame = False
    If i = UBound(arr) And buf = arr(UBound(arr)) Then
        IsAllElementsTheSame = True
    End If
End Function
```